# Raspberry pi camera and opencv and python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, arduino, raspberry-pi3, smbus

I have the code below and I want to modify it in many parts :

how can I use Raspbery Pi camera instead USB camera?

I will be grateful for anyone who gives me a hint or write the right code.

The code is :

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import smbus
import cv2
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x04

def sendData(value):
    bus.write_byte(address, value)
    return -1
def readData():
    state = bus.read_byte(address)
    return state
def ColorProcess(img):
    imgHSV = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img) ,8 ,3)
    cv.CvtColor(img, imgHSV, cv.CV_BGR2HSV)
    imgProcessed = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img) ,8 ,1)
    cv.InRangeS(imgHSV, (100, 94, 84), (109, 171, 143), imgProcessed)
    return imgProcessed
def main():
    width = 320
    height = 240

    capture = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)
    cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
    cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
    cv.NamedWindow("output", 1)
    cv.NamedWindow("processed", 1)

    while True:
        frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
        cv.Smooth(frame, frame, cv.CV_BLUR, 3)
        imgColorProcessed = ColorProcess(frame)
        mat = cv.GetMat(imgColorProcessed)
        moments = cv.Moments(mat, 0)
        area = cv.GetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0)
        moment10 = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0)
        moment01 = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1)

        if (area > 60000):
            posX = int(moment10/area)
            posY = int(moment01/area)
            ali = long(2000000)

            state = readData()
            if state == 1:
                sendData(posX)
                sendData(posY)

            print 'x: ' + str(posX) + 'y: ' + str(posY)

        cv.ShowImage("processed", imgColorProcessed)
        cv.ShowImage("output", frame)

        if cv.WaitKey(10) >= 0:

            break

    return;

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I will high appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: One question per question, please

Comment: If you answer only one I will be grateful for you.

Comment: @ITLover I'd say that was a subtle hint that you should split it up into 3 separate questions if you want it answered.

Comment: Thanks for  advice. I will separate it.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in LX Terminal in Pi.It will take care of drivers.

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```